# Realtime data management on webapp in a SOA environment (remote backend)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, asynchronous, websocket

My system is composed by a web portal (**Spring**-based) and a remote backend (**J2EE**-based) that exposes APIs to provide services.
An user should be capable to deploy a certain PaaS service on cloud (this process is managed by the backend) starting from the web portal and see the deployment status in realtime.

**Note:** the mentioned *deployment* just represents a complex operation.

In order to deploy a service as said, I defined on the backend a **long running transaction** that includes two parts: **synchronous** and **asynchronous**.

The first one exposes a **RESTful WebService**, used to start the deploy process. It returns the unique id of the started transaction.

```
String lrtId = myRESTClient.startDeploy(someInfo);
```

The other part is useful to check the state of progress: it have to return an information that summarizes the deployment status (e.g. *in progress*, *finished*, *stopped*, a *percentage of completion*, a *timestamp*, etc.).

To fetch this info in realtime, I thought about two solutions:

- Exposing this second part as another **WebService** and calling it by
  polling;
- Exposing it through **WebSocket** (and by using also other tools, for instance **STOMP**).

Note that, for security reasons, backend endpoints have to be private, thus users cannot call directly  the *asynchronous* part (by script): only the webapp must be able to communicate with the backend.
To overcome this constraint, I thought to define a dedicated web-resource by Spring Web: its controller should hide the communication between portal and backend, retrieve and provided realtime data to another web-resouce (in this case, a web page).

The image below summarizes the scenario:

[image: Scenario]

Being newbie on this use-case, I would like to know some suggestions about the proposed solutions.

Are they adequate? Which is the better? There are important info to know in order to implement them? Is there something wrong?

Comment: Not what you asked for, but probably of interest: http://wamp.ws/ This provides you with both RPC (roughly REST-like) _and_ Publish & Subscribe facilities in one protocol. A browser only needs 1 WebSocket connection to do both. Also the RPC is fully asynchronous, hence you don't run into limitations with REST like browsers only allowing 6 HTTP connections to a given origin.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. You have to consider that I cannot consume the WebService directly by JavaScript. It is accessible only by passing through the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, polling will consume more resources (the poll) than necessary, the best should be to use Websocket.

I personnally use websocket the JMS way: sending JMS MDBs (message driven beans) (for example at each calls of any of my DAOs within a many-DAOs-trasaction) that are then transformed by the broker (it works at least on AMQ) in a STOMP over WebSocket Client (and make a client correspondance with a technical WebSvc and WebSocket queue id).

STOMP over WebSocket have also the advantage to be transactionnal too, so you can know that your computation ended when you received all ACK and didn't get a Rollback: it avoids on more WebService call in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have some notes about the *double* WebSocket? (Browser - Webapp and Webapp - Backend)

Comment: I never heard about _double_ Websocket.My browser communicates with the backend sending STOMP over websocket messages (transformed into JMS messages to the server) and inter (server)apps communication is made with simple JMS MDBs.